# State mutation is prohibited inside of reducers

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

Using @ngrx/store this error popped up:

```
index.js?4b23:19 State mutation is prohibited inside of reducers.
(anonymous) @ index.js?4b23:19
(anonymous) @ index.ts:54
rootReducer @ index.ts:70
_initialStateFactory @ ng2.ts?2a33:24
AppModuleInjector.createInternal @ module.ngfactory.js:425
NgModuleInjector.create @ ng_module_factory.js?95b1:132
NgModuleFactory.create @ ng_module_factory.js?95b1:100
(anonymous) @ application_ref.js?0421:340
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js?e3a6:229
onInvoke @ ng_zone.js?b62b:269
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js?e3a6:228
Zone.run @ zone.js?e3a6:113
NgZone.run @ ng_zone.js?b62b:138
PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone @ application_ref.js?    0421:338
(anonymous) @ application_ref.js?0421:389
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js?e3a6:229
Zone.run @ zone.js?e3a6:113
(anonymous) @ zone.js?e3a6:509
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js?e3a6:262
Zone.runTask @ zone.js?e3a6:151
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js?e3a6:405
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?e3a6:336
main.browser.ts:18 TypeError: Cannot set property 'actions$' of undefined
at CatBibleEffects (catBible.effects.ts:15)
at combination (utils.ts?b1fc:23)
at index.js?39b4:125
at index.js?4b23:16
at index.ts:54
at rootReducer (index.ts:70)
at _initialStateFactory (ng2.ts?2a33:24)
at AppModuleInjector.createInternal (module.ngfactory.js:425)
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.create (ng_module_factory.js?95b1:132)
at NgModuleFactory.create (ng_module_factory.js?95b1:100)
at application_ref.js?0421:340
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js?e3a6:229)
at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.js?b62b:269)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js?e3a6:228)
at Zone.run (zone.js?e3a6:113)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `State mutation is prohibited inside of reducers` error seems to be returned when errors are caught from a reducer... here's the `ngrx-store-freeze/dist/index.js` code where the `catch` that returns this error lives...

```
function storeFreeze(reducer) {
    return function (state, action) {
        if (state === void 0) { state = {}; }
        deepFreeze(state);
        // guard against trying to freeze null or undefined types
        if (action.payload) {
            deepFreeze(action.payload);
        }
        var nextState;
        try {
            nextState = reducer(state, action);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('State mutation is prohibited inside of reducers.');
            throw error;
        }
        deepFreeze(nextState);
        return nextState;
    };
}
exports.storeFreeze = storeFreeze;
```

Therefore your error may truly be related to state being inappropriately altered or it could just mean that an uncaught error propagated out of a call to your reducer...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It is a bug with ngrx, it shouldn't do this, it should display the underlying error.

Answer (score 1):

This error had nothing to do with my effects file or my action file.  I forgot to rename the reducer function after copying from a similar file.  This also caused the call to this reducer to be named wrong in the main root reducer file as well.